# Динамическое изменение атрибута поля

Tags: c#, asp.net

В ASP.net MVC используются кастомные атрибуты для полей enum:

```cs
public enum UserType
{
    [EnumFieldText("Agent's user")]
    AgentUser = 1,
    [EnumFieldText("Restricted")]
    ManagerLimited = 2
}
```

Возможно ли их динамическое изменение(внедряется мультиязычность - их описания нужно динамически менять)? Такой вариант ничего не выдает:

```cs
System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UserType))
```

Comment: Возможно, некорректно указал: GetCustomAttributes пытался получить список атрибутов, однако он был пустым. Вопрос еще актуален

Comment: Все еже Актуально